# How to compare/replace non-ASCII chars in array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I have a large char array, which contains Czech diacritical characters (e.g. "á"), coded in UTF-8. I need to replace them to their ASCII equivalents (e.g. "a"), because program must work on Windows (Linux console accepts these chars perfectly).
I am reading array char by char and writing content into string.
Here is code I am using, this doesnt work:

```
int array_size = 50000; //size of file array
char * array = new char[array_size]; //array to store file contents
string ascicontent="";

if ('\u00E1'==array[zacatek]) { //check if char is "á"
                ascicontent +='a'; //write ordinal "a" into string
            }
```

I even tried replacing '\u00E1' with 'á', but it also doesnt work. Guessing there is problem that these chars are longer than ascii.

How can I declare the non-ascii char, so it could be compared?

Comment: The Windows console and command-line arguments do support Unicode.  Unfortunately, in order to take advantage of this, you have to use Windows-specific functions instead of Standard C++ ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `char` is a single byte, however UTF-8 can use multiple bytes to encode a single character. In particular U+00E1 is encoded as two bytes: 0xC3 0xA1. So you can't do what you want with just comparing a single `char`.

There are multiple ways that you might be able to tackle your problem:

A) First, try googling for "windows console utf-8" and see if that gives anything which might make things just work without having to alter the characters at all. (I don't know if anything can work for you, I've never tried this.)

B) Convert the data to wide characters (`wchar_t`) using [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [mbstowcs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) and then google how to use `wcout` or such to output UTF-16 to the console.

C) Use [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert the data from UTF-8 to UTF-16. Then use [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert from UTF-16 to the console's code page, relying on the fact that it can automatically "best fit" common characters (such as "á" to "a").

D) If you really only care about a limited set of characters (such as only the accented characters in the Czech code page), then you could possibly write your own lookup table of UTF-8 byte sequences and your desired replacements. You just need to be doing comparisons on the UTF-8 by those multiple bytes rather than individual chars. Among various tools out there, I've found [this page](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) helpful for seeing how characters are encoded in various ways.

Which of these make the most sense for your program depends on various factors, such as how easy or hard it might be to keep the Windows-specific pieces from conflicting with the Linux-specific or cross-platform parts.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me how UTF-8 chars works in C++.I never thought this could be bigger problem. 
After bigger research I pointed out, that there is not UTF-8 directly compatible command line, so A) is sadly not appliable. Found out that probably D) is only solution that will keep my code clean and multiplatform. Mentioned page with encoding is awesome help! I am currently using sstream to load hex value of char and then comparing it. I will have to add about 22 if statements for each character, but with few tested chars it already works :)

Answer (score 0):

`char` in C is not unicode, it is really a byte; it only gets converted to a glyph by the terminal console you happen to use. On some Linux implementations (like Debian) it defaults to UTF-8, so if your program outputs a sequence of bytes encoded in UTF-8, your terminal will display the proper glyph. If you know that `array` is UTF-8 encoded, you must check for the proper byte sequence.

**Edit:** take a look at [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: And the proper sequence of bytes for the example `\u00E1` is [`\xc3\xa1`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e1/index.htm).

Answer (score -2):

Please take a look at this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character.
And I believe this code might help you:

```
std::wstring str(L"cccccááddddddd");
std::replace( str.begin(), str.end(), L'á', L'a');
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It'd be great if you could explain why this solution helps solve the problem. There are lots of newbies on Stack Overflow, and they could learn something from you... and what may be really obvious to you won't be to somebody new to the field :)